# Following tutorial to connect postgres db to node project - failing at running script to create table

Tags: linux, node.js, postgresql, ubuntu

i am following a [guide](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/02/12/postgresql-and-nodejs/#.VfNu1WwViko) on how to use postgres + node.  I have gotten to the point of creating table creation script.

here is the code I am using from the tutorial:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/todo';

var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
var query = client.query('CREATE TABLE items(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, text VARCHAR(40) not null, complete BOOLEAN)');
query.on('end', function() { client.end(); });
```

However, when I do the step of `node models/database.js`, I receive the following error:

```
ram@ram-windows-xp-ubuntu:~/Development/Web/Projects/node-postgres$ node models/database.js
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/ram/Development/Web/Projects/node-postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:539:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/ram/Development/Web/Projects/node-postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:366:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ram/Development/Web/Projects/node-postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

I am new to using the ubuntu and I tried to follow the steps from [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) but confused.  Sorry for the bother friends please if you can do the needful I will be humbled.

Comment: The default password for postgres is probably something very imaginative like 'postgres'.

Comment: hi friend.   you are right... i am not very smart :(  thank you for helping me.  i am sorry for wasteing your time buddy.  simple.  thanks a lot sir

Comment: hey no problem - it happens to everyone :)